# How do I set attributes using prop values in styled-components v4 + TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

## Summary

**Given:**

```
const Link = styled.a`
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
`;

type ButtonProps = React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;
const LinkAsButton = styled(Link).attrs<ButtonProps>
>(({
  as: 'button',
  className: 'btn btn-primary'
})`
  border: solid 1px red;
`;
```

**How do I pass button specific props (e.g. disabled) to `LinkAsButton`?**

Repo (includes branch for v3 and v4) demonstrating issue:  https://github.com/arteforme/v3-v4-styled-components-migration

## Version 3

In v3, I'm able to do the following:

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "styled-components": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3333"
  }
```

**Component definition**

```
type ButtonProps = React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;

const Link = styled.a`
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
`;

const LinkAsButton = Link.withComponent('button')
  .extend.attrs<ButtonProps>({
  className: 'btn btn-primary'
})`
  border: solid 1px red;
`;
```

and in consuming code, I can specify button specific props (e.g. disabled, form, etc) on the `LinkAsButton` component.

## Version 4

In v4, I'd like to achieve the same; however, I've not been successful in determining how to go about doing so.  Per the latest documentation, I've updated `LinkAsButton` to no longer call `extend` or `withComponent` and instead wrap `Link` in a call to `styled` and uses `as` to specify the tag.  The v4 version looks like:

**package.json**

```
dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8.14",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.14",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
```

**Component definition**

```
const LinkAsButton = styled(Link).attrs<ButtonProps>
>(({
  as: 'button',
  className: 'btn btn-primary'
})`
  border: solid 1px red;
`;
```

and in consuming code, I specify `disabled={true}` on a `LinkAsButton` instance, but this does not compile.  Instead, the following error results:

*Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick, HTMLAnchorElement>, "type" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | ... 257 more ... | "referrerPolicy"> & { ...; }, "type" | ... 261 more ... | "referrerPolicy"> & Partial<...>, "type" | ....'.  TS2322*

### Reviewing attrs definition

Taking a look at the definition file, I notice that two generic arguments can be specified.

```
attrs <
  U,
  NewA extends Partial<StyledComponentPropsWithRef<C> & U> & {
    [others: string]: any;
  } = {}
    > (
      attrs: Attrs<StyledComponentPropsWithRef<C> & U, NewA, T>
    ): ThemedStyledFunction<C, T, O & NewA, A | keyof NewA>;
```

From what I can gather, `C` is the wrapped component and I believe `NewA` is NewAttributes.  I'm not able to determine what U is in this case, but I try specifying the second generic parameter.

```
const LinkAsButton = styled(AnchorLink).attrs<{}, ButtonProps>`
  // omitted for brevity
`
```

And in doing so, that results in the following error:

*Type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes' is not assignable to type 'Partial, HTMLAnchorElement>, "type" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | ... 257 more ... | "referrerPolicy"> & { ...; } & ButtonHTMLAttributes<...>>'.
    Types of property 'onCopy' are incompatible.*

With that information in hand, I try:

```
const LinkAsButton = styled(Link).attrs<
  {},
  { as: string; className: string; disabled?: boolean }
>({
  as: 'button',
  className: 'btn btn-primary'
})``;
```

Which works as I can now specify `disabled` in the markup, but not any other button specific props (e.g. `form`)

## Non ideal solution

One approach would be to do the following:

```
const LinkAsButton = styled(Link)<ButtonProps>`
  border: solid 1px red;
`;
```

Consuming code:

```
<div className="App">    
    <LinkAsButton as="button" className="btn-btn-primary" disabled={true}>
        First button
    </LinkAsButton>
    <LinkAsButton as="button" className="btn-btn-primary" disabled={true}>
        Second button
    </LinkAsButton>
</div>
```

However, this would lead to a lot of code duplication :(.

Comment: Have you tried to add ..props in your button definition, after the as definition?

Comment: Do you mean in the call to `.attrs()`?  If so, yes I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Got it working by moving the generic param after the call to .attrs.

```
const LinkAsButton = styled(Link).attrs
({
  as: 'button',
  className: 'btn btn-primary'
})<ButtonProps>`
  border: solid 1px red;
`;
```

Now any prop defined in ButtonProps can be set in the JSX

Comment: I think it's worthwhile marking this as the answer.